# How to set opacity of background colour of graph with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, alpha

I've been playing around with Matplotlib and I can't figure out how to change the background colour of the graph, or how to make the background completely transparent.

Comment: facecolor/set_facecolor?

Comment: But how do I use set_facecolor?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

If you just want the entire background for both the figure and the axes to be transparent, you can simply specify `transparent=True` when saving the figure with `fig.savefig`.

e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(10))
fig.savefig('temp.png', transparent=True)
```

If you want more fine-grained control, you can simply set the facecolor and/or alpha values for the figure and axes background patch.  (To make a patch completely transparent, we can either set the alpha to 0, or set the facecolor to `'none'` (as a string, not the object `None`!))

e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

fig.patch.set_facecolor('blue')
fig.patch.set_alpha(0.7)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(range(10))

ax.patch.set_facecolor('red')
ax.patch.set_alpha(0.5)

# If we don't specify the edgecolor and facecolor for the figure when
# saving with savefig, it will override the value we set earlier!
fig.savefig('temp.png', facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), edgecolor='none')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Setting the `facecolor` to `'none'` did not work for me; setting `alpha` to `0.0` did.

Comment: For me setting facecolor to `"None"` did work. Setting it to `None` doesn't work.

Comment: What if not using `savefig`? I'm attempting to write to a buffer.

Comment: @alphabetasoup Setting the corresponding global `rcParams` should do the trick, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62466259/8176827) below

Answer (score 30):

Another way is to set the appropriate **global** [`rcParams`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#matplotlib-rcparams) and simply specify the [colors](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colors.html#specifying-colors). Here is an MWE (I used the RGBA color format to specify the alpha/opacity):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams.update({
    "figure.facecolor":  (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3),  # red   with alpha = 30%
    "axes.facecolor":    (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5),  # green with alpha = 50%
    "savefig.facecolor": (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.2),  # blue  with alpha = 20%
})

plt.plot(range(10))
plt.savefig("temp.png")
plt.show()
```

The `figure.facecolor` is the main background color and the `axes.facecolor` the background color of the actual plot. For whatever reason, `plt.savefig` uses `savefig.facecolor` as the main background color rather than `figure.facecolor`, so make sure to change this parameter accordingly.

`plt.show()` from the code above results in the following output:

[image]

and `plt.savefig("temp.png")` results in this output:

[image]

If you want to make something completely transparent, simply set the alpha value of the corresponding color to 0. For `plt.savefig`, there is also a "lazy" option by setting the rc-parameter `savefig.transparent` to `True`, which sets the alpha of all facecolors to 0%.

Note that altering the [`rcParams`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#matplotlib-rcparams) has a **global effect**, so bear in mind that all your plots will be affected by these changes. However, this solution can be extremely useful if you have multiple plots, or if you want to change the appearance of plots where you cannot change the source code.

Comment: I also think using the RGBA alpha channel is the most elegant.