# How do you save Matplotlib figure with an opaque white border?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, transparency

When saving a Matplotlib figure from a Jupyter notebook, how do I override the default transparent border so it will be opaque?

Looking at the [`savefig` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html), there are several parameters that seem like they would affect this but actually do not seem to do anything. Here is an example.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 100)
ax.plot(x, np.sinc(x))
plt.savefig(
    'test.png', 
    transparent=False, # no change
    frameon=True, # no change
    edgecolor='blue', # no change (want 'white' but 'blue' should be noticeable)
    facecolor='red', # no change (want 'white' but 'red' should be noticeable)
    alpha=1, # no change
)
```

Here is the result.  StackOverflow does not illustrate the transparency, but note that the edge is not `'blue'` and the face is not `'red'`.

[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4708018/3585557) mentions setting `fig.patch.set_alpha(1)` which turns out to work, regardless of the `savefig` parameters.  Adding this command to the example code resolves the problem.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fig.patch.set_alpha(1)  # solution

x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 100)
ax.plot(x, np.sinc(x))
fig.savefig('solved.png')
```

[image]

It turns out this is specific to Jupyter notebooks, and is probably a bug (I only have version 4.4.0).  When I run the following code above from the command line, I instead get the desired behavior (change `'red'` to `'white'` to get the opaque white border).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 100)
ax.plot(x, np.sinc(x))
plt.savefig(
    'test.png', 
    # transparent=False, # no change
    # frameon=True, # no change
    # edgecolor='blue', # no change
    facecolor='red', # no change
    # alpha=1, # no change
)
```

[image: red]